# CakePHP Auth Component: Unable to login "You are not authorized to access that location." message is displayed

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a table named "userinformations ". I want to use emailid and password fields as login credentials for my site.
Have added the below codes in respective files. But when I login I am in same login page with a message "You are not authorized to access that location."

**app/app_controller.php**

class AppController extends Controller {

```
var $components = array('Auth','Session');

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Userinformation';
    Security::setHash("md5");
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'emailid', 'password' => 'password');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'Userinformations', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'Userinformations', 'action' => 'updateuserprofile');
    //sign up  is a page which don't requires to login
    $this->Auth->allow('signup');
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';

} 
    function isAuthorized() {

    return true;

}
```

}

**Model : userinformation**

```
class Userinformation extends Appmodel
{
    var $name='Userinformation';
    var $primaryKey = 'userid';

    .
        .
    .
    .
    .
    .   
    .
function hashPasswords($data){
if(isset($this->data['Userinformation']['password'])){
    $this->data['Userinformation']['password']= md5($this->data['Userinformation']['password']);
    return $data;
}
return $data;
}
function beforeSave() {
$this->hashPasswords(NULL,TRUE);
return TRUE;
} 
}
```

**Controller : UserinformationsController**

```
function login(){

}
function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

**view : userinformations/login.ctp**

```
<?php

echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $form->create('userinformation', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $form->input('user.username');
echo $form->input('user.password');
echo $form->end('Login');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need that hashPassword(), and rewrite the form:

```
echo $form->create('userinformation', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $form->input('emailid');
echo $form->input('password');
echo $form->end('Login');
```